# Change chapter title format in report document without titlesec?

Tags: formatting, report

I'm working with `report`and I'd like to change title format without `titlesec`, because my headers and footers are implemented using fancy style, and it produces errors.

By default, `\chapter`command gets:

```
Chapter 1

Chapter Title
```

I'd like to have:

```
1 Chapter title
```

Can someone please help me to get this result?

Thank you.

**EDIT :**

I tried with your code, and I almost get what i'm looking for, but it appears an error that place symbol @ before word chapter. I let my code in order to find the solution easier. Thank you again.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Temas de numeración de páginas
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{graphicx}%Introducir encabezados LaTex
\usepackage{hyperref}%Hiperlinks índices
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\graphicspath{{../Figuras/}}
\date{date}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Modify chapter format
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\vspace*{50\p@}%
{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \huge\bfseries
    % \@chapapp\space % removed
    \thechapter
    ~% \par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@ % replaced
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge % \Huge % replaced
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Eliminar visualización hipervínculos índices
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=black,
filecolor=black,
linkcolor=black,
urlcolor=black
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Definición de formato de hoja

\setmargins{2.5cm}        % margen izquierdo
{1.25cm}                  % margen superior
{16.5cm}                  % anchura del texto
{23.3cm}                  % altura del texto
{5pt}                     % altura de los encabezados
{1.5cm}                   % espacio entre el texto y los encabezados
{20pt}                    % altura del pie de página
{1.5cm}                   % espacio entre el texto y el pie de página

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\headheight 40pt 
\headsep 30pt

% aqui definimos el encabezado de las paginas pares e impares.


\chead[\thedate \\ Título de Proyecto]{\thedate \\ title}
\rhead[\leftmark]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

% aqui definimos el pie de pagina de las paginas pares e impares.
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\fancypagestyle{capitulo}{      
\fancyhead[C]{\thedate \\ title}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}


%Encabezado especial índices
\fancypagestyle{especial}{
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%COMIENZO DOCUMENTO

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%CREACIÖN DE LOS ÍNDICES

\tableofcontents 
\thispagestyle{especial}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\chapter{Chapter}\label{capitulo}
\thispagestyle{capitulo}
bla bla bla


\section{Section}\label{seccion}
ble ble ble 

\end{document}
```

This is the way that currently is shown:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a few modifications of the `\@makechapterhead` macro:

- Remove `\@chapapp\space` to remove the `Chapter` word;
- Replace `\par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@` by `\nobreakspace{}` to replace the line break by a space (`~` has a different meaning if `babel` is loaded);
- Replace `\Huge` by `\huge` to get the size right (you could also replace `\huge` by `\Huge` to get a larger font size).

> [image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries
        % \@chapapp\space % removed
        \thechapter
        \nobreakspace{}% \par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@ % replaced
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge % \Huge % replaced
    \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works perfectly with the last edit.

Comment: @Daniel You're welcome :) If it did solve your problem you can mark the question as "solved" by clicking the accept button (the checkmark ✓ to the left side) of the answer that solved the problem.

Comment: Great job @PhelypeOleinik, can you help me with how to add a . (dot) after the chapter number.

Comment: @relinquere Just add the dot after `\thechapter`

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrreprt` instead

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
bar
\end{document}
```