# Recreating a Fancy Chapter Style

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, chapters, titles

I am attempting to create the chapter style below in LaTeX, where the grey box represents a different image chosen for each chapter. I'd like the chapter title (in this example "Complex Numbers") and the chapter number (in this example 9) to be vertically centred in the section of the box shown in the picture. The word 'Chapter' should also feature centred in a black box attached at the intersection of the two dotted lines. I thought it might be easier to start with the Bjornstrup chapter style and see if I can edit it to get the desired effect. However, my attempt (below) was unsuccessful. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could show me how to achieve the desired output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
%%%% ******************************************************* added
\newcommand{\colortitlechap}{\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}} % color of the chapter title <<<
\newcommand{\colornumberchap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter number <<<<
\newcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox[rgb]{.129,0.1,0.82}} % color of the background rules <<<

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{0pt}% 
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise0pt%
    \hbox{\colornumberchap\CNoV\thechapter}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[dotted, black, ultra thick] (2cm,0cm) -- (2cm,2.5cm);
        \draw[dotted, black, ultra thick] (0,1.2cm) -- (\textwidth,1.2cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}\\%
}

\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
}

\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}\\%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
}

\makeatother
%%*******************************************************************************
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Introduccion}
    \section{One}   
    \chapter{Technical content}
    \section{Two}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt by changing the `\@makechapterhead` definition (reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471456/133968). The code is pretty much self explanatory for anyone with knowledge of `tikz`.

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{chapterbg}{cyan}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471456/133968
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
%    \vspace*{50\p@}%
%    {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
%        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
%        \huge\bfseries
%        % \@chapapp\space % removed
%        \thechapter
%        \nobreakspace{}% \par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@ % replaced
%        \fi
%        \interlinepenalty\@M
%        \huge % \Huge % replaced
%        \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
%        \vskip 40\p@
%    }
    {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]
            \pgfmathsetmacro\lw{\linewidth/1cm} % linewidth in cm
            \pgfmathsetmacro\boxw{\lw} % box width
            \pgfmathsetmacro\boxh{0.25*\lw} % box height
            \pgfmathsetmacro\hruleloc{0.3*\boxh} % location of horizontal rule
            \pgfmathsetmacro\vruleloc{0.75*\boxw} % location of horizontal rule
            \pgfmathsetmacro\figwidth{0.9*(\boxw-\vruleloc)} % figure width
            \pgfmathsetmacro\figheight{0.9*(\boxh-\hruleloc)} % figure height
            
            % outer box
            \fill [chapterbg] (0,0) rectangle (\boxw,\boxh);
            
            % horizontal and vertical lines
            \draw [very thick, dotted] (0,\hruleloc) -- +(\boxw,0);
            \draw [very thick, dotted] (\vruleloc,0) -- +(0,\boxh);
            
            % "chapter"
            \node at (\vruleloc,\hruleloc) [anchor=north west, fill=black] {\color{white}\bfseries\itshape Chapter};
            
            % figure placeholder
            \node (fig) [text width=\figwidth cm, text height=\figheight cm, fill=gray, inner sep=0pt] at ($0.5*(\vruleloc,\hruleloc)+0.5*(\boxw,\boxh)$) {};
            \draw (fig.south west) -- (fig.north east);
            \draw (fig.south east) -- (fig.north west);
            
            % chapter name and counter
            \node [align=center, text width=0.8*\vruleloc cm] at ($0.5*(0,\hruleloc) + 0.5*(0.8*\vruleloc,\boxh)$) {\bfseries \LARGE\itshape #1};
            \node [left, scale=2] at ($0.5*(\vruleloc,\hruleloc)+0.5*(\vruleloc,\boxh)$) {\Huge \bfseries \thechapter};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{A long title\\[2pt]with custom line breaks}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]